# LS coupling vs jj coupling as extreme cases - related to the relevant vector sum model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

The difference between light and very heavy atoms reflects itself in these two schemes.
My question is why one scheme for the vector sum is necessarily the right & suitable sum model for one case, and the 2nd scheme suits the 2nd case ?
In other words, why & how the relative magnitude of the respective terms in the Hamiltonian, namely for LS & the central field (residual), results in the order the summing of the angular momenta (orbital & spin) ?
In my eyes, this focuses us on the fundamental problem.
Thanks, Bentzy.

Comment: It is based on the perturbative term in the Hamiltonian. If you look a Hamiltonian for a system, you can guess which term is least with respect to other terms and based on that, you can choose a suitatable basis (LS or jj) for further calculations. This method can be found on any Many body QM books.

Comment: Yes, this quite follows what's already known. Let me put it in other words: why does the stronger interaction precede in the order of addition ? Why does the relative strength of the involved interactions dictate one scheme of addition, rather than the other ? How does the different mathematics reflect different physical pictures of leading term in the Hamiltonian ? I hope the point is much clearer now.

Comment: Its simply that "strong" coupling will have effects in shorter time than the weak coupling.